# k piles with $k(k+1)/2$ balls

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

Given $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ balls arranged in $m$ piles.

A player picks a ball from each pile and creates a new pile.

As a result, piles with one ball disappear, and a new pile with $m$ balls is created.

For example ($k=2$), if we sort the piles by their size:
$$(1,1,1)\rightarrow (3) \rightarrow (1,2) \rightarrow (1,2)$$

It is easy to see, that for any $k$:
$$(1,2,\dots,k)\rightarrow (1,2,\dots,k)$$

Let $(1,2,\dots,k)$ be denoted as the **stationary state**

Show that no matter what is the initial configuration of piles, the piles configuration would converge to the **stationary state**.

Comment: This is the game sometimes called "Bulgarian solitaire".

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the comment by [Michael Lugo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173/michael-lugo), I found a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00885.pdf) covering the "Bulgarian solitaire" problem and the solution.

I knew the solution is based on setting a function that decreases in every move, however I was having problem coming up with the function.

The function the paper describes, is the potential energy (height times mass times g) of the balls, when the piles are vertical and placed in a box, in the case that the box is rotated to 45 degrees.

[image: Figure from the paper]

See full paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00885.pdf)

I've tested their solution in `python` and it works:

```
f = lambda x: sum([(len(x)-i)*t+(t+1)*t/2.0 for i,t in enumerate(x)])
```

Where x is sorted tuple that describes how many balls are in each pile.

you can see my full code [here](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/154da2bad95068e6dedaf3d9e511c3d6)